# firstLineHeadIndent make number disappear on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

On iOS 11,it is displayed fine:

[image]

But on iOS 9,these number disappeared:
[image]

The orange text label use attributedText `firstLineHeadIndent`:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
style.firstLineHeadIndent = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width + 4;
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.descLabel.text];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:NSMakeRange(0, self.descLabel.text.length)];

self.descLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

**if I don't use `firstLineHeadIndent`,these number would appear:**

```
//style.firstLineHeadIndent = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width + 4;
```

[image]

My project is here:https://github.com/CaiWanFeng/BeautifulView

I can't understand why these number disappeared on iOS 9,hope someone can tell me the reason.

Comment: I think it's the `[self.descLabel sizeToFit];` in `CQPickTimeAlertItem` that causes the issue. If you do (not viable solution): `CGFloat w = self.frame.size.width; [self.descLabel sizeToFit]; self.descLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 30); [self.descLabel sizeToFit]; self.descLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.descLabel.frame.origin.x, self.descLabel.frame.origin.y, w, self.descLabel.frame.size.height);` it works, but removing the first `self.descLabel.frame =` fails too in this case (second label with various line causes issue). iOS9 issue?

Comment: Use `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` instead?

Comment: @Larme If I only delete `[self.descLabel sizeToFit];` these numbers would appear,but if I add `boundingRectWithSize:options:context` these numbers would disappeared, too.